# Caching in Azure Functions using python

Tags: python, azure, caching, azure-functions

I am using Azure Queue as a trigger in my azure function.

My azure function connects to mongoDB and fetches some collections.

Some of this collections are common for all queue jobs and can vary from 1000 Documents to 1 Million Documents.I need to cache this collections.

I don't want to use any external caching services(Azure Redis Server etc).

Is there a way to use Disk Caching(or any other kind of caching)?

I am using Python 3.5.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [DiskCache](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/diskcache/index.html) to cache the mongoDB results.

> DiskCache is an Apache2 licensed disk and file backed cache library, written in pure-Python, and compatible with Django.